# Drag and Drop ListView Items Located in Sliding Drawer into Area below Sliding Drawer

Tags: android

I am trying to drag and drop `ListView` items into a new activity using a `OnItemLongClickListener` as seen here:

```
Drag_and_Drop_App.java (snippet):

// implement event when an item on list view is selected via long-click for drag and drop
mListAppInfo.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener(){

@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView parent, View view,
        int pos, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // get the list adapter
    AppInfoAdapter appInfoAdapter = (AppInfoAdapter)parent.getAdapter();
    // get selected item on the list
    ApplicationInfo appInfo = (ApplicationInfo)appInfoAdapter.getItem(pos);
    // launch the selected application
    Utilities.launchApp(parent.getContext(), getPackageManager(), appInfo.packageName);
    return true;
}


});
}
}
```

Right now, I only made it start the activity, but I want to make the item drag and drop.

How can I do this?

I've looked at the drag and drop tutorial [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html) but am really confused on how I can include these methods. (Right now the only coding I have for dragging and dropping the items in the list is the coding above)

My `ListView` is a collection of all the user's installed applications using packagemanager.

Here is what I am trying to do (for clarity):

[image]

Comment: what is Utilities object? And dragging and dropping from one activity to another seems like an odd thing to want to do since generally only one activity is on the screen at once meaning if you are dragging to another activity the first one is not going to be visible any more. Nonetheless you'd have to "attach" your item data as an extra to the intent you are using to launch the second activity and then inside of onStart() in the second activity pull that data out of the intent extra and use it to populate an item on the screen which you could then drop.

Comment: @FoamyGuy Utilities is my class that handles things like the user clicking the item to open it. I want to drag and drop from one activity to another (well in a way) because I have my listview in a sliding drawer so I want to move the listview items from the sliding drawer into the area the sliding drawer is over. So the whole activity is on one screen.

Comment: So, unless I am misunderstanding, would I still have to go about "attaching" the extra to the intent I am going to use to launch the second activity since there is not really an "second activity"?

Comment: The title of your question "Drag and Drop ListView Items Into New Activity" uses the phrase "new activity" which implies a different activity than the one that you are currently in. Which implies a second activity. If there is actually not a second activity then I don't understand what you are asking or trying to achieve. perhaps reword your question to make a bit more clear, maybe even include some screen shots if possible.

Comment: I reworded my question title and added a quick sketch of what I am trying to do